# Do browsers cache inline Javascript, and if so, how to force a reload?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

We recently moved to jQuery 1.6 and ran into the attr() versus prop() back-compat issue. During the first few hours after the change was deployed everything was fine, then it started breaking for people. We identified the problem pretty quickly and updated the offending JS, which was inline.

No we have a situation where some folks are still having issues. In every case thus far, I could get the user up and running again by telling them to load the page in question then manually refresh it in the browser. So something must still be cached somewhere.

But there are basically only two potential culprits: First, the jQuery library itself, but this is loaded with the version number in the query string so I think browsers will be refreshing it in their cache. Second, the inline javascript. Is it possible that this is being cached in the browser?

We are using APC, apc.stat=1 so it should be detecting that the PHP files have changed. Just to be on the safe side I nuked the opcode cache anyway.

To summarize, I have two questions:

1. Could some browsers be ignoring the query string when jQuery is loaded?
2. Could some browsers be caching an older version of the inline javascript?

Any other ideas very welcome too.

UPDATE: In the course of checking that there wasn't any unexpected caching going on using Firebug, I discovered a case where the old jQuery library would load. That doesn't explain why we had trouble after deploying the site and before we updated the inline code, but if it solves the problem I'll take it.

Comment: If it was inline and that code was the real culprit, the actual file that contained it would have to be what was cached.

Comment: It sounds like your page is being cached, not specifically the inline JS...

Comment: Have you thought of browser caching headers? This makes the most sense to me.

Comment: The page in question is PHP, so it must be executed every time the page is loaded. I don't understand how that will be cached. It is possible that I'm missing something fundamental about the caching mechanism.

Comment: @Greg, can you give me a link to the page? I'll tell you if my browser caches it.

Comment: See the part I added to my answer below on caching.

Comment: Embarrassingly, in the course of looking at the caching behavior I found a case where jQuery 1.4 was loading. I have no idea how this explains what I saw, but I'll be happy if it solves the issue.

Comment: @PaulPRO, thanks a ton for offering to look at the page. It is behind a membership wall and therefore not completely trivial, but I might take you up on the offer if fixing the jQuery version doesn't do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to both your questions is no. *Unless* the whole page is being cached. A browser can't cache part of a file, since it would have to download it to know which parts it had cached and by that time it's downloaded them all anyways. It makes no sense :)

You could try sending some headers along with your page that force the browser not to use it's cached copy.

Comment: Thanks, this answer makes total sense. But how would the browser be caching a dynamic page generated by PHP? I'm assuming the browser can only cache the result of an HTTP GET to a specific URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the answers to your questions are 1) No and 2) Yes.

jQuery versions are different URLs so there's no caching problems there unless you somehow edit a jQuery file directly without changing the version string.

Browser pages (including inline javascript) will get cached according to both the page settings and the browser settings (that's what browsers do).  The inline javascript isn't cached separately, but if the web page is cached, then the inline javascript is cached with it.  What kind of permissible caching have you set for your web pages (either in meta tags or via http headers)?

Lots to read on the subject of web page cache control [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) and [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) if needed.

It is very important to plan/design an upgrade strategy when you want to roll out upgrades that works properly with cached files in the browser.  Doing this wrong can result in your user either staying on old content/code until caches expire or even worse ending with a mix of old/new content/code that doesn't work.

The safest thing to do is to change source URLs when you have new content.  Then there is zero possibility that an old cached page will ever get the new content so you avoid the mixing possibility.  For example, on the Smugmug photo sharing web site, whenever any site owner updates an image to a new version of the image, a version number in the image URL is changed.  Then, when the source page that shows that image is served from the web server, it includes the new image URL so, no matter whether the old version of the image is in the browser cache or not, the new version image is shown to the user.

It is obviously not always practical to change the URL of all pages (especially top level pages) so those pages often have to be set with short cache settings so the browsers won't cache them for long and they will regularly pull fresh content.

Comment: Sure, pages are cached, but this is a PHP file and will be executed every time the page loads, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The PHP file generates a web page that is sent to the browser.  That resulting web page (from two weeks ago) could be cached by a browser (depending upon cache-control settings).  Browser goes to visit that same URL.  If that web page is still in the browser cache and cache-control allows the browser to just use it, then no request is made to your server to re-render that web page and thus old content may be seen by the browser.

Comment: Thanks for persevering, but I'm afraid I still don't get it. If the output of the (PHP) preprocessor was cached on the browser client then surely none of the dynamic pages on the site would be... dynamic. This is why one doesn't specify an expires header for php files. So given that the rest of the site is loading new content every few seconds (and never something from 2 weeks ago) surely this isn't the issue?

Comment: It depends upon cache-control settings in the page/headers.  As PaulPro said, shows us the actual page URL and we can stop talking theoretically.

Comment: The detail and explanation in your updated answer is great, and I do version my assets and stylesheets. But the thing is that we are talking about PHP files in this particular case. If changing source URLs was a best practice then how would a WordPress based blog handle this when they upgrade to a new version. None of the existing URLs are going to change. Anyway, I think I found the issue and it was stupidity on my part and not caching that was to blame.

Comment: @Greg, the answer is they set short or no cache times on their pages. To a browser, a PHP file is the same as a static HTML file.  It's just a URL that it does a GET on.  It's the cache-control settings that tell the browser how long it can cache the file for.  A server that always wants the user to see fresh content sets the page for no caching.